# What does the pseudo of a non-invertible matrix signify?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

More specifically if there is a matrix whose two rows are exactly identically, its inverse can't be calculated because its determinant is 0. However, its pseudo-inverse can still be found out. Is there any significance of the pseudo inverse of such a matrix?

Comment: You could take a look here: [Ols](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares). The pseudoinverse is very important for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: Yes.

Long: Given the least-squares problem
$$\bar x = \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_{x\in\mathbb R^n} \|Ax-b\|_2$$
A solution is
$$\bar x = A^\dagger b$$
Where $A^\dagger = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$. Moreover all solutions are characterised by $\bar x + z$ where $Az = 0$ i.e. $z\in\ker A$.

Comment: Actually, $\arg\min_x\|Ax-b\|_2$ defines a set $\bar{x}+\mathrm{Ker}(A)$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Depending on the dimensions of $A$. Usually in LS, $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ with $m >> n$ and $\ker A = \{0\}$. But in general, yes.

Comment: @AlexR: independently of what you say, I cannot grok a reply that sounds like "usually no, but in general yes".

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen That means that while the remark is correct (that's why I altered the answer to include it), the usual applications of LS-problems (such as linear regression) feature a setting where $\ker A = \{0\}$.